# Shopware 6 App - Override .../storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

when i try to override the buy-widget.html.twig file. Shopware does nothing. Only the index override works. But not the sub file. My code is:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig' %}


{% block page_product_detail_buy_form %}
    <h1 style="background: green;">Test</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Is your environment in "APP_ENV=dev"? Otherwise an reinstall or update of your necessary as the templates are only reloaded for apps on install and update in prod environments. So give it a try to uninstall and install the app again,

Comment: I use dockware dev. Yeah thanks! After a reinstall its working.

Comment: Feel free to post this as your answer and accept it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you APP_ENV is set to "dev", the templates changes should be reloaded live when you make changes to the files or add new template files etc.

Otherwise an reinstall or update of your app is necessary as the templates are only reloaded for apps on install and update in prod environments.

Answer (score 7):

As one comment stated when changing or adding a template, the cache has to be cleared. When developing, preferably use `APP_ENV=dev` in your `.env` file, to enable the development mode.

The `dev` mode adds the developer toolbar (at the bottom of the page), in the "TWIG" panel all rendered templates, including their inheritance, are listed.

Also note that for the `buy-widget.html.twig` template there are two occurrences, once in the [`page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig), which is used when no layout is assigned to the product and once in [`component/buy-widget/buy-widget.html.twig`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/component/buy-widget/buy-widget.html.twig), which is used in combination with product layouts.